# How to create a global keypress event listener with Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I am developing an app that I would like to be completely driven by keyboard inputs rather than any mouse clicks. It has been developed using Marionette and whilst I am fully able to respond to events on an input, I am really struggling to respond to events on views that don't contain any inputs.

```
events: ->
    'keyup #discovery-region' : 'logKey'

logKey: (e) ->
    alert("Key pressed")
    console.log("Key pressed " + e.which)
```

In my index.html file I have

```
<div class="discovery" id="discovery-region"></div>
```

In this circumstance I want to handle controlling keyboard inputs on the discovery region. However I would also like for this region to be removed at a later date and another region be in it's place. Should I create a some global mechanism for handling events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to archive this by creating a Layout view, inside this Layout I define a region, inside this region I can show what ever view I want and swap them if I need to, In the layout view I also define an event listener for the keyup inside the region.
It worked for me, the only trick is that the focus has to be on the Region div. but i think you can add more listeners to your other regions...

```
var MyLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
 template: "#layout-template",
 events : {
    "keyup #aRegion" : "test"
 },
 regions: {
   aRegion: "#aRegion"
 },
 test : function () {
  console.log("hi");
}                                             
});
```

here is the working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rayweb_on/b7tbX/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would try using events to communicate:

```
events: ->
  'keyup #discovery-region' : 'triggerKeyEvent'

triggerKeyEvent: (e) ->
  MyApp.trigger("discovery:region:keypress", e)
```

Then, in the views that need to respond to it, you simply add event listeners for that event:

```
myViewInstance.on("discovery:region:keypress", (e) ->
  // do something with the keypress event
```

Since your app now broadcasts the keypress events, each view can simply listen to them when the view is created/shown. Problem solved!

As a side note, depending on why the views need to react to keypresses, you might also want to look into triggerMethod to directly trigger a view's method, but I don't think that's what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful as it provides a nice clean solution to your problem

https://github.com/Puppets/marionette-cookbook/tree/master/recipes/hotkeys